# How do I check if an element is present in list of records in DAML?

Tags: daml

Suppose Event is record with fields like eventName and eventParameter. I want to assert for the condition if some eventName say "EV1" is present in list of records. For list of native Data types (let say Parties) I can simply check with `(elem in following)` as given in docs. Can anyone help me what would be the syntax for record data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elem` is an instance of a more general function `any : (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` which takes a predicate and a list of elements and returns true if the predicate holds for at least one element in the list. `elem x xs` is equivalent to `any (\y -> x == y) xs`.

Using `any` you can express your example as follows:

```
data Event = Event with
  eventName : Text

test = scenario do
  assert $
    any (\r -> r.eventName == "EV1")
        [Event with eventName = "EV1"]
  assert $ not $
    any (\r -> r.eventName == "EV1")
        [Event with eventName = "EV2"]
```